# Updating a prisma field using the "where" clause causes an error

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

I'm having this error when updating a field depending on the **id** of the model but I'm getting a **Invalid `prisma.resource.update()` invocation:** error.

This is my query:

```js
const upvote = await prisma.resource.update({
  where: {
    id: body.resourceID,
  },
  data: {
    totalUpvotes: {
      increment: 1
    },
    userUpvoted: true,
  },
});
```

When I  run the same query but use a string value instead of the `body.resource` variable,

```js
const upvote = await prisma.resource.update({
  where: {
    id: "cl5njhgc90435e8sx2o6d",
  },
  data: {
    totalUpvotes: {
      increment: 1
    },
    userUpvoted: true,
  },
});
```

I'm getting the desired output. Can you tell me why this might be happening

> I'm using NextJS, Prisma and PlanetScale for this application

Following is the full output of the error.

```
Request error PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `prisma.resource.update()` invocation:

{
  where: {
?   id?: String
  },
  data: {
    totalUpvotes: {
      decrement: 1
    },
    userUpvoted: false
  }
}

Argument where of type ResourceWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument. Available args are listed in green.

Note: Lines with ? are optional.

    at Document.validate (C:\Users\Ammaar\resourcehub\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:48195:20)
    at PrismaClient._executeRequest (C:\Users\Ammaar\resourcehub\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:50632:17)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async PrismaClient._request (C:\Users\Ammaar\resourcehub\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:50572:18)
    at async __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/meta/downvote.js:17:28)
    at async Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\Ammaar\resourcehub\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:179:9)
    at async DevServer.runApi (C:\Users\Ammaar\resourcehub\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:381:9)
    at async Object.fn (C:\Users\Ammaar\resourcehub\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:488:37)
    at async Router.execute (C:\Users\Ammaar\resourcehub\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:213:36) {
  clientVersion: '4.0.0'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value and type (`typeof`) of `body.resourceID`? Please add more information about the error.

Comment: The value of `body.resourceID` is a uniquely generated cuid and it is a `String` type.

Comment: Ok... but when the application is running and you try to execute the code, what is the value/type of variable `body`. Try with a simple `console.log(body)` | `console.log(typeof body.resourceID)`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... `body` is an object and `resourceID` is a string inside `body`

Comment: I know that, but when you run the application is still true? You must check it

Comment: Yes it is I checked

Comment: More information about the error?

Comment: Can you add the full output of the `Invalid prisma.resource.update() invocation` error to your post? That should contain a more descriptive error about what exactly is going on. For example, the id you're passing in might not actually exist in your backend, or there might be something else going on. But without seeing the full error it's hard to know exactly what's wrong

Comment: I've added the full output of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you're receiving and your code, `body.resourceID` is being evaluated to `undefined` within your code. Make sure `body.resourceID` is a string by the time the code executes - is it possible your body contains a variable named something other than `resourceID`, and it's just a typo?